# Error building Quantlib involving Boost (Ubuntu)

Tags: boost, quantlib

I am attempting to build QuantLib 1.9 on my machine (Xubuntu 16.04), and I got Boost via "sudo apt-get...."

QuantLib compiles fine until the following sequence of events:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/packages/QuantLib-1.9/test-suite'
```

There are two calls to libtool, the first looks like this:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++ -g -O2 -o quantlib-test-suite
```

Followed by nearly 100 *.o files, and terminated by this string:

```
libUnitMain.la ../ql/libQuantLib.la -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

There is a second call to libtool after that one:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/quantlib-test-suite
```

Also followed by 100 *.o files, and terminated by this string:

```
./.libs/libUnitMain.a ../ql/.libs/libQuantLib.so -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

Here is where the error crops up, and the build then fails:

```
 quantlibtestsuite.o: In function `make_test_case':
 /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255: undefined reference to boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
 /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255: undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
 americanoption.o: In function `make_test_case':
 /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255: undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
 /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255: undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
 americanoption.o: In function `boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)':
 /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255: undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
 amortizingbond.o:/usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255: more undefined references to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)' follow
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:1075: recipe for target 'quantlib-test-suite' failed
 make[1]: *** [quantlib-test-suite] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/packages/QuantLib-1.9/test-suite'
 Makefile:601: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: What is the version of Boost that got installed, and what was your call to `./configure` exactly?

Comment: I configured via the following command line argument:

sudo ./configure --with-boost-include=/home/EmilioW/Downloads/boost_1_62_0 --with-boost-lib=/home/EmilioW/Downloads/boost_1_62_0/libs

The config.log file is quite large, and I can't post it here. I only see the error once the script attempts to compile the test-suite.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're compiling with a version of Boost and you're trying to link with another (you're saying that you got Boost via `apt-get`, which installs into `/usr`, but then you pass to `./configure` a path in your home directory).  This would explain why the linker is looking for a method in `boost::unit_test::ut_detail` that's not in the library.

If you want to use the version of Boost that came with `apt-get`, removing the boost paths from the call to `./configure` should make it work.  If you want to use the one you have installed locally, you should first check that you actually have the compiled libraries in `/home/EmilioW/Downloads/boost_1_62_0/libs`. If they are in fact there, and if you don't need Boost for something else, you can use `apt-get` to uninstall the packaged version. If you need both installed, you'll have to check the order in which the compiler and linker list the `-I` and `-L` paths and ensure that the ones you want come first...

Comment: Hi Luigi, I had to purge my system from other Boost versions. I.e. you were right in this case. I wanted to buld everything from source, but I made the error of apt-getting Boost at an earlier time. Removing did not clean the system properly.